# Unable to ping VirtualBox host only interface

Tags: linux, networking, macos, virtualbox

On my macOS Monterrey machine I am running Ubuntu as guest on VirtualBox 6.1.30 r148432. In VirtualBox I've enabled the host-only adapter, and I see interface vboxnet0 on macOS:

```
ifconfig vboxnet0
vboxnet0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00
    inet 192.168.56.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.56.255
```

I am unable to ping `192.68.56.1` from either macOS or from the guest. I can ping the guest OS's IP address for the host-only adapter, `192.68.56.101`, from macOS.

I want my my guest to access a service running on macOS, so I thought I'd have that service listen on `192.186.56.1`.

There are [other questions like this one on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28017921/117259) with this problem, but there is no answer that works for me. I checked the firewall settings, but I don't see any logs in `appfirewall.log` (from Console -> Log Reports).

Comment: Host Only is secured access so what you see is apparently normal.

Comment: Please edit your question to include what exact version of VirtualBox you are using. There are odd “quirks” (aka: bugs) that show up in specific versions of VirtualBox that are often fixed by an upgrade of VirtualBox. Also you state, “Other people are experiencing this problem, but there is no answer.” Who are these other people? What are their other answers? It’s not like we all hang out and know everything about everyone’s issues. You need to provide links context so others can better understand the issue and what others have advised.

Comment: FWIW, the 6.x version of VirtualBox is up to VirtualBox 6.1.40. That said, as @John explains, that is the expected behavior. The host only adapter (`192.68.56.101`) exists as something that should respond to pings and generally be the interface you interact with. The machine address of `192.168.56.1` is not what you access. Is there a more specific issue happening here? Why does this matter to you? Just use the host only interface (`192.68.56.101`).

Comment: I want my my guest to access a service running on macOS, so I thought I'd have that service listen on `192.186.56.1`.

Comment: Use NAT or Bridged Networking NOT Host Only.

Comment: I've used that before, but I think with those interfaces the communication goes through my wireless router, which is slow, and if the router is down, the host and guest can't communicate. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Host only is a very limiting interface (by design). You cannot expect it to be flexible like the other interfaces.

Comment: Is there a way to have the guest communicate with the host but keep the communication with the local machine? I was expecting that if the host and can talk to the guest over this interface, the opposite should be possible.

Comment: You should be able to get the guest to connect to the host by using the IP address of the host machine and not `192.68.56.1`. Try it out.

Comment: I can't ping the host's IP address from guest. Even if I were able to ping, would this go though my router?

Comment: @user2233706 Nope. If you want your guest VM to interact with any device outside of the host, you need two use NAT or Bridged Networking. That’s that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, I cannot ping vboxnet0 interface IP address. However, I find that I can run a service on that interface access it from the guest, which is all I need.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.